# Is there anyway to use boost python wrappers in headers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

Is there anyway to use BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE in a header file? For instance, I'd like to be able to declare this Module

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Status_Effect)
{
    boost::python::class_<StatusEffect>("StatusEffect")
        .def("GetPriority", &StatusEffect::GetPriority)
        .def("GetDescription", &StatusEffect::GetDescription)
        .def("GetName", &StatusEffect::GetName);
}
```

in a header file. Whenever I try however, it complains about multiple definitions. Does anyone know of a way to do the wrapping in a header file?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want that in a header?

Comment: There is no point in putting that in a header. the compiler and boost::python will get your code exported form the binary either way, and there is nothing else useful you can do with that in c++

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround: What's inside of the parentheses is just ordinary C++ code. So you could move that part into an inline function.

For example, you could put this into the header:

```
inline void DeclareStatusEffect()
{
  boost::python::class_<StatusEffect>("StatusEffect")
    .def("GetPriority", &StatusEffect::GetPriority)
    .def("GetDescription", &StatusEffect::GetDescription)
    .def("GetName", &StatusEffect::GetName);

}
```

And this into your source file:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Status_Effect)
{
  DeclareStatusEffect();
}
```

You can also look at what the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro does, and maybe there's a way to put even more into the header, but that's probably not safe to do with future versions of Boost.Python, even if you get it to work.